# Use CERTBOT to generate certificate files to upload to plesk in Godaddy Windows Hosting

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate, plesk, certbot

I'm trying to use free SSL Certificates for domains hosted at Goddady Windows Hosting.
I managed to generate a domain certificate using Certbot but it generates the following .pem files:
 - chain.pem
 - cert.pem
 - fullchaim.pem
 - privkey.pem

I need to use the certificate in a domain hosted in Godaddy's Windows Hosting using Plesk that seems to use only .crt files, like bundled .crt file:
[Plesk bundled upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbhkd.jpg)
or individual files:
[Plesk indivudual files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIdnS.jpg)
How can I convert or generate the necessary files to upload to Plesk?
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a programming site; yours is a web administration question. Maybe you'll have better luck at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/ .

Comment: Filenames (and their extensions) are irrelevant. You can call it `.pem` or `.crt` it does not matter (outside of braindead OS that requires specific extensions in which case you have to rename the file), the only important thing is the content. PEM is a form of encoding of content (either certificate or keys). `.crt` just means, **by convention** typically a certificate (in opposition to `.key` for example, again by convention, for (private) keys). Also since you are paying a provider, did you ask it for help?